# DEPRECATION: HTTParty will no longer override `response#nil?`. What does this Deprecation warning mean?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, httparty

This question is probably poorly structured so please bear with me, I'm new at this.

I'm trying to build a simple web scraper but every time i run my code i get this warning in terminal. I have tried to follow the link to the github issues hoping i would get a clearer explanation but i didn't understand it there either. Tried googling, but nothing there either.

```
[DEPRECATION] HTTParty will no longer override `response#nil?`.
This functionality will be removed in future versions.
Please, add explicit check `response.body.nil? || response.body.empty?`.
For more info refer to: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/568
```

I guess what i want to know is, in basic terms, what does this warning mean? and is there something i should do different from now on when using the `HTTParty` gem?

Comment: It's pretty much what the deprecation notice says. You are calling `response.nil?` somewhere in your code and HTTParty tells you that this method will be removed. You can call `response.body.nil?` or `response.body.blank?` instead. The details behind this change can be found at https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/568

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was annoying me as well. You are probably passing the response from HTTParty.get to some other code that is testing for nil. I was passing the body to Nokogiri::HTML and that code was eventually calling HTTParty.response.nil?. To fix, I started sending the "body" to Nokogiri instead of the response object. Quite a few people will probably run into this as the Nokogiri example code with this pattern is all over the place.

I now use this:

```
doc = HTTParty.get('https://some/site')
parsed ||= Nokogiri::HTML(doc.body)
```

instead of before when getting the warning it was:

```
doc = HTTParty.get('https://some/site')
parsed ||= Nokogiri::HTML(doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
url = "https://www.startech.com.bd/laptop-notebook/laptop"

  unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(url)
  parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
```

I was facing same error as yours

```
[DEPRECATION] HTTParty will no longer override `response#nil?`. This functionality will be removed in future versions. Please, add explicit check `response.body.nil? || response.body.empty?`. For more info refer to: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/568
/home/abir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/nokogiri-1.11.1-x86_64-linux/lib/nokogiri/html/document.rb:209:in `parse'
```

So changed the code as Jeremy Mullin said and it is working fine now.

```
url = "https://www.startech.com.bd/laptop-notebook/laptop"

  unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(url)
  parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page.body)
```